# Difference between RDNSS and RDNSSes

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

Can someone explain what the difference is? I find both abbreviations in my resarch about autoconfiguration solutions without clear distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is singular, and the second is plural. Literally that simple.

For those in passing, RDNSS is short for "Recursive DNS Server". ([RFC 6106](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6106#section-3))